# Ubuntu 14.04 Server installation

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, data-loss, user-data

Hi I'm trying to upgrade an old version of ubuntu server to ubuntu-server-14.04. However there is a large amount of data under /home (1.4 TB) which I do not want to lose. Nor do I prefer to make a hard back up (takes ages + should arrange for resources!). I'm using a bootable USB to install 14.04. I'm not really sure how to proceed at 'Partition disks' stage of the installation to achieve what I need. Attached is the pic of the stage during installation.

Suggestions ?

**Edit:** 
Okay, I forgot to add a crucial part of the problem. The old version is a 32-bit version. The 14.04 version I'm trying to install is 64-bit version. 64-bit OS is the primary motivation for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ubuntu upgrade process does not effect files in the /home folder. You can run the embedded ubuntu update by the following

To upgrade to a newer release, from a terminal prompt enter:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

It is also possible to use do-release-upgrade to upgrade to a development version of Ubuntu. To accomplish this use the -d switch:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

***EDIT***
Follow my instructions to install Ubuntu 64 bit without losing your current software configuration:

1. In a terminal execute sudo dpkg --get-selections > ~/softwarelist.
   Install the x64 Ubuntu over the existing one. If asked to preserve
   Home, say yes.
2. Execute sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/softwarelist.
3. Execute sudo apt-get -f install. You will have some errors, but all
   should be fine.
4. Reboot.

This procedure is valid for the 12.04, it can change with older/newer versions.

*Source* [Upgrading ubuntu 12.04 32 bit to 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409584/upgrading-ubuntu-12-04-32-bit-to-64-bit)

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add a crucial part of the problem. The old version is a 32-bit version. The 14.04 version I'm trying to install is 64-bit version. 64-bit OS is the primary motivation for the upgrade.

Comment: I edited my solution